# Optimizing fortran code with intel VTune analyzer

Tags: optimization, fortran, performance-testing, intel, intel-vtune

I am working with a fortran project to simulate vegetation dynamic. The code is slow so I am always on the look for ways to optimize it.
I have been reading that there exist a "rule" saying that usually 90% of the time is spent on 10% of the code. To find out these bottlenecks I have started using the intel VTune performance analyzer. The simulation analysis shows that a large amount of time is spent in specific parts of the code as shown in the images [image: Figure 1]. The most time consuming part of `leaftw_derivs` is shown in the next figure. [image: Figure 2]

The code referred to in the analysis is shown below.

```
   !---- Update soil moisture and energy from transpiration/root uptake. ------------------!
   if (rk4aux(ibuff)%any_resolvable) then
      do k1 = klsl, mzg    ! loop over extracted water
         do k2=k1,mzg
            if (rk4site%ntext_soil(k2) /= 13) then
               !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!
               !     Transpiration happens only when there is some water left down to this !
               ! layer.                                                                    !
               !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!
               if (rk4aux(ibuff)%avail_h2o_int(k1) > 0.d0) then
                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!
                  !    Find the contribution of layer k2 for the transpiration from        !
                  ! cohorts that reach layer k1.                                           !
                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!
                  ext_weight = rk4aux(ibuff)%avail_h2o_lyr(k2) / rk4aux(ibuff)%avail_h2o_int(k1)

                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!
                  wloss_tot      = 0.d0
                  qloss_tot      = 0.d0
                  wvlmeloss_tot  = 0.d0
                  qvlmeloss_tot  = 0.d0

                  do ico=1,cpatch%ncohorts
                     !----- Find the loss from this cohort. -------------------------------!
                     wloss         = rk4aux(ibuff)%extracted_water(ico,k1) * ext_weight
                     qloss         = wloss * tl2uint8(initp%soil_tempk(k2),1.d0)
                     wvlmeloss     = wloss * wdnsi8 * dslzi8(k2)
                     qvlmeloss     = qloss * dslzi8(k2)
                     !---------------------------------------------------------------------!


                     !---------------------------------------------------------------------!
                     !      Add the internal energy to the cohort.  This energy will be    !
                     ! eventually lost to the canopy air space because of transpiration,   !
                     ! but we will do it in two steps so we ensure energy is conserved.    !
                     !---------------------------------------------------------------------!
                     dinitp%leaf_energy(ico) = dinitp%leaf_energy(ico)  + qloss
                     dinitp%veg_energy(ico)  = dinitp%veg_energy(ico)   + qloss
                     initp%hflx_lrsti(ico) = initp%hflx_lrsti(ico)      + qloss
                     !---------------------------------------------------------------------!

                     !----- Integrate the total to be removed from this layer. ------------!
                     wloss_tot     = wloss_tot     + wloss
                     qloss_tot     = qloss_tot     + qloss
                     wvlmeloss_tot = wvlmeloss_tot + wvlmeloss
                     qvlmeloss_tot = qvlmeloss_tot + qvlmeloss
                     !---------------------------------------------------------------------!
                  end do
                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!



                  !----- Update derivatives of water, energy, and transpiration. ----------!
                  dinitp%soil_water   (k2) = dinitp%soil_water(k2)    - wvlmeloss_tot
                  dinitp%soil_energy  (k2) = dinitp%soil_energy(k2)   - qvlmeloss_tot
                  dinitp%avg_transloss(k2) = dinitp%avg_transloss(k2) - wloss_tot
                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!
               end if
               !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!
            end if
            !------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
         end do
         !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
      end do
      !------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
   end if
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
```

I have a very basic understanding of optimization but I don't see what could be done here to improve the code. In particular I don't understand what *Instructions Retired* means and how to go about it. Is there a way here to speed up computations?

**EDIT**

Giving it a bit more thought I realized that there are some easy optimizations here. For example moving the conditional `if (rk4aux(ibuff)%avail_h2o_int(k1) > 0.d0) then` outside the loop as well as moving the `tl2uint8(initp%soil_tempk(k2),1.d0)` outside the innermost loop.

However I cannot really understand the reason for the supposedly long times VTune gives: the 3 lines

```
             dinitp%leaf_energy(ico) = dinitp%leaf_energy(ico)  + qloss
             dinitp%veg_energy(ico)  = dinitp%veg_energy(ico)   + qloss
             initp%hflx_lrsti(ico) = initp%hflx_lrsti(ico)      + qloss
```

are just performing an addition. This should be extremely fast but instead the analyzer says that a lot of time is spent there. Why would that be?

**EDIT2**

I rewrote the entire loop trying to optimize as much as I could. This is the code I came up with

```
   !---- Update soil moisture and energy from transpiration/root uptake. ------------------!
   if (rk4aux(ibuff)%any_resolvable) then
      do k1 = klsl, mzg    ! loop over extracted water

               !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!
               !     Transpiration happens only when there is some water left down to this !
               ! layer.                                                                    !
               !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!
               if (rk4aux(ibuff)%avail_h2o_int(k1) > 0.d0) then

                wloss_tot_k1 = 0.d0

                do ico=1,cpatch%ncohorts
                     !----- Integrate the total to be removed from this layer. ------------!
                     wloss_tot_k1 = wloss_tot_k1 + rk4aux(ibuff)%extracted_water(ico,k1)                     
                     !---------------------------------------------------------------------!
                end do
                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!

                  do k2=k1,mzg
                    if (rk4site%ntext_soil(k2) /= 13) then
                  do ico=1,cpatch%ncohorts
                     wloss         = rk4aux(ibuff)%extracted_water(ico,k1) * ext_weight
                     uint_here1    = wloss * uint_here

                     dinitp%leaf_energy(ico) = dinitp%leaf_energy(ico) + uint_here1
                     dinitp%veg_energy(ico)  = dinitp%veg_energy(ico)  + uint_here1
                     initp%hflx_lrsti(ico)   = initp%hflx_lrsti(ico)   + uint_here1
                  end do
                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!

                  wloss_tot     = wloss_tot_k1 * ext_weight                   
                  wvlmeloss_tot = wloss_tot * dslzi8(k2) * wdnsi8
                  qvlmeloss_tot = wloss_tot * dslzi8(k2) * uint_here


                  !----- Update derivatives of water, energy, and transpiration. ----------!
                  dinitp%soil_water   (k2) = dinitp%soil_water(k2)    - wvlmeloss_tot
                  dinitp%soil_energy  (k2) = dinitp%soil_energy(k2)   - qvlmeloss_tot
                  dinitp%avg_transloss(k2) = dinitp%avg_transloss(k2) - wloss_tot
                  !------------------------------------------------------------------------!


               end if
               !---------------------------------------------------------------------------!
            end do
            !------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
         end if
         !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
      end do
      !------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
   end if
   !---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------!
```

It's a bit long so I don't expect people to go through it. If I run the analyzer now I get considerably reduced times (from 290s to 185s, although in real simulations the speed up seems to be slightly less). [image: New times]

However when looking at the sampling there is still a considerable amount of time spent in operations that I would not expect to be "expensive". I still don't get what *Retired instructions* means and how to go about it. For the moment I think this is enough and I guess that the proper way of getting a further speed up would be to make use of openMP capability as Holmz is suggesting.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The compile option -qopt-report=4 (linux spelling) should produce a report about optimizations which would be important to understanding this.  If a large amount of time is spent in those additions, it could be from waiting for the operands to become available; the purpose of VTune is to facilitate investigation as well as to identify hot spots.  ifort doesn't necessarily optimize well a case like this with several sum reductions in parallel; if that is the problem, it will take some experiments to find improvement.

Comment: Assuming that your comment means you were successful in moving the exponentiation ahead of the loop, you should show the corresponding VTune profile and compiler optimization report.

Comment: Yes I'm still testing this portion with the modifications. I will try to post an update asap.

Comment: !$OMP SIMD REDUCTION clause may help the three summing lines. Possibly three loops may be better than one. Those are part of a structure/TYPE... So they are NOT linear/CONTIGUOUS and your stride is not 1, and the memory addresses are all over the place.
I would try busting those fields out into separate vector/arrays, ... So basically testing only that "function" in a standalone sense using a small program to drive it.

Comment: I am not too familiar with OpenMP so for the moment I wanted to concentrate my efforts on just plain optimization. As I specified in the Edit I already got a pretty decent improvement. I guess that taking care of the 5 or so most time consuming portions of the code could already give a 50% speed up. Only problem is that now most of the bottlenecks seem to be the mathematical functions (that I cannot pinpoint the location of).

Comment: Would it make any sense to convert `wloss` into an array so you could do `wloss(ico)=rk4aux(ibuff)%extractedwater(ico,k1)⋅extweight` or even `wloss(1:cpatch%ncohorts)=rk4aux(ibuff)%extractedwater(1:cpatch%ncohorts,k1)⋅extweight` and later `dinitp%leaf_energy(1:cpatch%ncohorts) = dinitp%leaf_energy(1:cpatch%ncohorts) + uint_here * wloss(1:cpatch%ncohorts)` outside the loop; i.e. trade space for speed. I'm curious if array operations and contiguous memory buy you any speed.